Concern About DC Input Current Compatibility: Will My DC-DC Converter Work with a 48V 120Ah Lithium-Ion Battery Pack?
I’m seeking advice on the compatibility between my DC-DC converter and a 48V lithium-ion battery pack. Specifically, I’m concerned about the maximum input current ratings. Here are the relevant specifications:
DC-DC Converter (Part No: DC 48-13.2_10A):

Input Voltage Range: 42 - 60 VDC
Input Current Maximum: < 5.0 A
Output Voltage: 13.2 VDC
Output Current: 10 A constant, 15 A peak
Output Line & Load Regulation: Tolerance ± 2% at cable
Output Ripple / Noise: < 250 mV / < 1000 mV Pk-Pk
Protections: Overload, Short Circuit, Over Voltage
Operating Temperature: 0°C to +50°C
Enclosure: Aluminium with IP65 rating
Weight: 800 grams

48V 120Ah Lithium-Ion Battery Pack:

Nominal Voltage: 46.8 V
Operating Voltage Range: 35.7 V to 54.6 V
Continuous Discharge Current: 120 A
Instantaneous Discharge Current: 200 A
Charge Voltage Range: 41 V to 54.6 V
Discharge Voltage Range: 54.6 V to 41 V
Battery Management System (BMS): Included
Operating Temperature Range: 0ºC to 50ºC

Concern: The battery pack can provide a continuous discharge current of 120 A and an instantaneous discharge current of 200 A, whereas the DC-DC converter has a maximum input current rating of less than 5 A. I’m worried that the high input current from the battery might exceed the converter’s maximum input current rating.
Questions:

Will the DC-DC converter be able to handle the current from the battery pack safely, or is there a risk of overloading it?
Are there any additional precautions or solutions to ensure that the converter operates correctly with the battery pack?

I appreciate any insights or recommendations!

In general*, when you consider a power source, you need it to be capable of delivering current that is at least the current the load needs. The source being capable of delivering more amperes is pretty much a non-issue.
Just imagine you plugging your phone charger into the wall outlet. The wall outlet is capable of delivering 10-16 ampere (depending on where you live) and your load (the phone charger) will use at most half an ampere. Everything works.
You have to worry if the situation is the other way round - the load needs more amperes than the source can deliver. In this case, the problems may range from the load not being up to performance, the load not working at all or something breaking or burning. Avoid situations like these if you don't know exactly what you are doing.

On the other hand, your battery and converter specs reveal another problem that may or may not be an issue for you.
Battery: Operating Voltage Range: 35.7 V to 54.6 V
(this is the range from fully depleted to fully charged battery)
DC-DC converter: Input Voltage Range: 42 - 60 VDC (this is generally the range of a Li-ion battery with a nominal voltage of 52V)
The converter will work OK with a fully charged battery, but as you keep draining the battery, its voltage will go below these 42V the load (your DC-DC) expects in order to work properly. This will happen WAY before the battery is fully depleted.
You will be able to use like 50%-80% of your real battery capacity.
(how much exactly depends on a lot of factors)
What will happen below 42V depends on your converter design, but the things you may expect are: reduced max power, reduced output voltage, or a complete shutdown. The converter breaking because of low input voltage is unlikely.
The converter may as well run flawlessly below 42V, but it is up to you to try and find out.

* This assumption is not correct when you match a battery charger to a battery. In this case, the source (the charger) has to deliver LESS amperes than the battery is able to accept. If your battery calls for 4A charger, it will be happy with 2A one as long as you are happy to wait more, but using 5A charger with the same battery is not OK.
